# jQuery mobile listview with filter and checkbox - li click event not fired

Tags: jquery, listview, checkbox, filter, click

I'm trying to make a really long jQuery mobile listview in popup. Listview should meet following conditions:

- thumbnail on left
- checkbox on right
- the checkbox should change checked on entire `li` click
- it should have filter

I'm able to do all this without filter. After adding filter strange behavior occurs:

1. If the listview is not scrolled down at all, listener gets fired, checkbox gets selected, but after that filter textbox gets focus.
2. If it is scrolled down, I'm able to click the checkbox and check or uncheck it, but whenever I try to click the `li` the event isn't fired and the listview just scrolls up and filter textbox gets focus.

Listview:

```
<ul id="friends" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search friends">

  <li id="some_id" data-icon="false">
      <a>
           <img src="img_url" alt="img_alt">
           <div class="row middle-xs">
               <div class="col-xs-10 row">
                   <div class="col-xs-12"><p>Friend name</p></div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-2 row end-xs">
                   <input id="some_id" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="b" type="checkbox">
               </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>

    <!--- ... --->

</ul>
```

Listener:

```
$(function() {
    $('ul li').click(function(e) {
        if (!$(e.target).is('input[type=checkbox]')) {
            var checkbox = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');
            var checked = $(checkbox).is(":checked");
            $(checkbox).prop('checked', !checked);
        }

        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
});
```

How do I get my listener fired when the listview is scrolled down and prevent the listview from scrolling up and filter textbox from getting focus? Calling `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried to wrap everything inside `li` with `label`? If there is checkbox inside label it can be triggered by click on any part of the label and you don't need js to toggle it. Also you probably should remove `<a>`, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes you're right the `<a>` tag was useless. And if I try to wrap everything inside the label, jQuery mobile no longer displays nice thumbnails on the left because it needs the `img` to be the first direct child of `li`. See [jQuery mobile documentation](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/listview/#Thumbnails).